# Locale specific behavior in the regex library?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, locale

When I imbue a regex object with a particular locale, how does it affect the matching behavior? Does it affect collation, or anything else? I can't seem to find an explanation anywhere.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/10540305/83805

Comment: @DonStewart: I was only interested in C++ specifics. Locale specific behaviour isn't necessarily the same everywhere I imagine.

Comment: Locale affects POSIX-compliant regex engines, which is at least the starting point for most regex libraries out there.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It affects at least the following:

- Collation: the regex `[a-f]` imbued with a French locale should match the character é.
- Similarly, `\w` in a Finnish locale should match the character ä (but `[a-z]` should *not*, as å, ä and ö collate after z in Finnish. In German, however, `[a-z]` should match ä.)
- In a Unicode compatible locale, the [Unicode equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) algorithm should be used, so that composed forms of a character match a decomposed form and vice versa.
- With a POSIX-compatible regex flavor (basic, extended, awk, grep, and egrep), the [POSIX character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) should be locale-aware: `[=e=]` should match é in a French locale but not in an English locale.

Answer (score 3):

On the spanish locale, please note that "ch" and "ll" are not considered single letters in the alphabet any more, as this was changed by relevant entities. I could not find the exact date, but it right now "ch" and "ll" are two letters:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ll

I think implementations now reflect that fact.