# Grep pattern matching lower case string enclosed in double quotes

Tags: regex, string, grep

I'm having a bit of an issue with grep that I can't seem to figure out.  I'm trying to search for all instances of lower case words enclosed in double quotes (C strings) in a set of source files.  Using bash and gnu grep:

```
grep -e '"[a-z]+"' *.cpp
```

gives me no matches, while

```
grep -e '"[a-z]*"' *.cpp
```

gives me matches like "Abc" which is not just lower case characters.  What is the proper regular expression to match only "abc"?

Comment: Your second regex looks fine. I tried it and it doesn't match upper case characters.

Comment: @Mike you're forgetting locale-specific collating order.

Comment: @Don Thanks, didn't even think about that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're forgetting to escape the meta characters.

```
grep -e '"[a-z]\+"'
```

For the second part, the reason it is matching multi-case characters is because of your locale. As follows:

```
$ echo '"Abc"' | grep -e '"[a-z]\+"'
"Abc"
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ echo '"Abc"' | grep -e '"[a-z]\+"'
$
```

To get the "ascii-like" behavior, you need to set your locale to "C", as specified in  the grep man page:

> Within a bracket expression, a range expression consists of two
>   characters separated by a hyphen.  It matches any single  character
>          that  sorts  between  the  two characters, inclusive, using the locale's collating sequence and character set.  For example, in the
>          default C locale, [a-d] is equivalent to [abcd].  Many locales sort characters in dictionary order, and in these locales  [a-d]  is
>          typically  not equivalent to [abcd]; it might be equivalent to [aBbCcDd], for example.  To obtain the traditional interpretation of
>          bracket expressions, you can use the C locale by setting the LC_ALL environment variable to the value C.

Comment: Yup, stupid locales.  Also, why do I have to escape the +?  I would think that if I wanted a literal + I would escape it and that a bare + would be considered the metacharacter.

Comment: In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their  special  meaning;  instead  use  the  backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \). To get extended regexen, use -E

Answer (score 1):

Mask the +

```
grep -e '"[a-z]\+"' *.cpp
```

or use egrep:

```
egrep  '"[a-z]+"' *.cpp
```

maybe you had -E in mind:

```
grep -E '"[a-z]+"' *.cpp
```

The lowercase -e is used, for example, to specify multiple search patterns.

The phaenomenon of uppercase characters might origin from your locale - which you can prevent with:

```
LC_ALL=C egrep  '"[a-z]+"' *.cpp
```

Comment: I thought grep -e was egrep.  I guess I was mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, but since my habit is to use egrep, I tested egrep without looking closer to the -e option, and just after succeeding with egrep, I realized, that the -e should do a similar thing - I thought the same. But the correct option is -E, with capital E. Please lookup -e yourself in the manpage.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to escape the `+`:

```
grep -e '"[a-z]\+"' *.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess about with locales, this worked for me:

```
grep -e '"[[:lower:]]\+"'
```