# basic_regex throws bad_cast with char32_t

Tags: c++, regex, casting, stdstring

Why does the following code generate `std::bad_cast` exception?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::basic_string<char32_t> reg = U"^\\w";

    try
    {
        std::basic_regex<char32_t> tagRegex(reg);
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This sample on Ideone for convenience: https://ideone.com/Saea88

Using `char` or `wchar` instead of `char32_t` runs without throwing though (proof: https://ideone.com/OBlXed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_traits:

> To use std::basic_regex with other character types (for example, char32_t), a user-provided trait class must be used.

so you would have to implement `std::regex_traits<char32_t>`

and to see why there is no definition for it see here: [Why is there no definition for std::regex_traits<char32_t> (and thus no std::basic_regex<char32_t>) provided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708892/why-is-there-no-definition-for-stdregex-traitschar32-t-and-thus-no-stdbas)

Answer (score 1):

On GCC or Clang, the code compiles fine even with custom regex traits, but fails at runtime with `std::bad_cast`. If you've got yourself here, the issue comes from `std::use_facet<std::ctype<char32_t>>` throwing the error, because the current locale doesn't support it. You have to specialize `std::ctype<char32_t>` and set the global locale via `std::locale::global` to a new locale constructed using the old one and the specialized facet.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @AlexAngel You can find a working implementation [here](https://github.com/IllidanS4/PawnPlus/blob/4038e8e0ae4d3a6dcd376f91466527cbee8065b7/plugins/src/modules/strings.cpp#L164) and [here](https://github.com/IllidanS4/PawnPlus/blob/4038e8e0ae4d3a6dcd376f91466527cbee8065b7/plugins/src/modules/strings.h#L356).